# Python/Regex/Match/Search confusion

Tags: python, regex

I ran into this interesting case.  I wasn't sure of the precedence of the | operator so I've originally used non-capturing groups to separate my pipes.  However, this resulted in getting None for a match, removing the capturing groups also results in None.  However, specifying a single capturing group around them works.  This is strange to me.  I don't quite understand what's going on.  Any ideas?

Also, search works in all cases, as I'd expect...

```
re.match(r'^Details: WARNING|CRITICAL|ERROR', 'Details: CRITICAL asdfasdf')
None
re.match(r'^Details: (?:WARNING)|(?:CRITICAL)|(?:ERROR)', 'Details: CRITICAL asdfasdf
None
re.match(r'^Details: (?:WARNING|CRITICAL|ERROR)', 'Details: CRITICAL asdfasdf'
<_sre.SRE_Match at 0x1b27d98>
re.search(r'^Details: WARNING|CRITICAL|ERROR', 'Details: CRITICAL asdfasdf')
<_sre.SRE_Match at 0x1b27ed0>
re.search(r'^Details: (?:WARNING)|(?:CRITICAL)|(?:ERROR)', 'Details: CRITICAL asdfasdf')
<_sre.SRE_Match at 0x1b27e00>
re.search(r'^Details: (?:WARNING|CRITICAL|ERROR)', 'Details: CRITICAL asdfasdf')
<_sre.SRE_Match at 0x1b27e00>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your expression `^Details: WARNING|CRITICAL|ERROR` is interpreted as an alternation of these three regular expressions:

- `^Details: WARNING`
- `CRITICAL`
- `ERROR`

Since `re.match` (unlike `re.search`) requires that the match starts at the beginning of the string, it will fail to match `Details: CRITICAL` and `Details: ERROR`.

The best fix if you don't want a capturing group is:

```
r'^Details: (?:WARNING|CRITICAL|ERROR)'
```

This expression matches if any of the following regular expressions match (as intended):

- `^Details: WARNING`
- `^Details: CRITICAL`
- `^Details: ERROR`

Although `re.search` works fine here, it would make more sense to use `re.match` with this regular expression since you are only looking for matches at the start of the string.

Answer (score 2):

The first two are saying: match either "Details: WARNING", or "CRITICAL", or "ERROR".

The third one is saying: match "Details: ", followed by either "WARNING", "CRITICAL", or "ERROR".

The searches are saying: look in the string for either "Details: WARNING", or "CRITICAL", or "ERROR".

Matches start at the beginning of the string, which is why the first two don't work; searches scan the whole string.

Comment: Thanks, Ben, looks like Mark beat you to the punch.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the precedence of the `|` metacharacter is topped only by the grouping constructs `()` (and in a way, I suppose the character class `[]` delimiters, which turn it into a literal `|` character - but then it's a literal, not an "or operator").

Its just like the short-circuit "or" operators (`||` in Java, C/C++, C#, JavaScript, etc... or the `OrElse` in Visual Basic). You could also think of the nothing (zero-space, zero-characters) that is between literal characters as a "followed-by" "operator" that has higher precedence - but that's kind of a stretch.

Essentially, the expression `^Details: WARNING|CRITICAL|ERROR` is interpreted as:

```
^Details: WARNING   # assert at the beginning, then match literally "Details: WARNING"
|                   #  -OR-
CRITICAL            # match "CRITICAL"
|                   #  -OR-
ERROR               # match "ERROR"
```

while the expression `^Details: (WARNING|CRITICAL|ERROR)` is interpreted as:

```
^Details:           # assert at the beginning, then match literally "Details: "
(                   # begin capture group
  WARNING           #   match literally "WARNING"
  |                 #    -OR-
  CRITICAL          #   match literally "CRITICAL"
  |                 #    -OR-
  ERROR             #   match literally "ERROR"
)                   # end capture group
```

and the expression `^Details: (?:WARNING|CRITICAL|ERROR)` is interpreted only slightly differently as:

```
^Details:           # assert at the beginning, then match literally "Details: "
(?:                 # begin match (non-capturing) group
  WARNING           #   match literally "WARNING"
  |                 #    -OR-
  CRITICAL          #   match literally "CRITICAL"
  |                 #    -OR-
  ERROR             #   match literally "ERROR"
)                   # end match group
```

Hope that answers all your questions!

Comment: This is a good answer.  If Mark's answer wasn't clear to anyone or the regex syntax not familiar, this paints a very clear picture of what's going on.  However, make sure to see Mark's answer for the tidbit on match vs search in this case.